# Kafka consumer not getting any partitions assigned

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a microservice which has multiple instances running. It has a kafka consumer which reads a topic from the beginning. Following is how I create the consumer.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SystemEventDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

KafkaConsumer<String, SystemEventDef.SystemEvent> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
```

The consumer is polled using a timer, with 0 poll duration.

```
consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(0L))
```

Randomly, some instances of the microservice doesn't get any data at all from the topic, while other instances get the data without an issue. If I kill that microservice instance, a new instance gets spawned, and it will most probably start receiving the data from the topic without an issue.

I checked the partition assignment for the consumer with the method below.

```
consumer.assignment()
```

And it returns an empty set all the time, no matter how many times the `poll()` method is called, on the instances which faced the issue. Also for the other instances which work fine, `assignment()` returns an empty set in the beginning, but after a few `poll()` calls, it returns a non empty set.

What could be the reason for some consumers not getting any data randomly?

Why doesn't `assignment()` return a non empty set from right after the first `poll()` call for the instances which receive the data without an issue, and only return a non empty set after a random number of `poll()` calls?

Answer (score 0):

1. `poll()`: Fetch data for the topics or partitions specified using one of the subscribe/assign APIs. **It is an error to not have subscribed to any topics or partitions before polling for data**.
2. In the beginning, if the assignment hasn't happened yet, or the partitions are in the process of getting reassigned (kill that microservice instance to rebalance partitions), `consumer.assignment()` will return empty set. After the partition assignment, `consumer.assignment()` will return the set of partitions currently assigned to this consumer.
3. Assignment is before polling data, and that's all. But when rebalance happens, you cannot ensure `consumer.assignment()` always get consistant result.